# How realign segments of image in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, python-imaging-library

This is the image look like:-
[image]

I want  to be look like this.:- 
[image]

Please look, in the second picture button of the image is laved up. I use a software to do this they called this option as segment to 20. I don't have any idea ho to do it in python can anyone please help me ? I am using python 2.7 and i am also new to python so please describe clear with code example. I have tried Opencv vector spacing to do it but all the time give me wrong image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved. If you edit the question, it's possible that the question can be prevented from being closed and the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well.

Comment: Is this for processing CAPTCHA  images?

Comment: no this is not  @PM2Ring

Comment: Ok, just checking. Sorry if I insulted you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off,  you need to find the objects (numbers) within your image and save them in `/objects` folder. You can do this by using `cv2.findContours()` in order to find the contours and then the bounding rectangle's coordinates with `cv2.boundingRect()` method.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('old_image.png') 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,11,2)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
i=0    
for cnt in contours:
     [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
     if h>60:
      cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),1)
      im3=im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
      cv2.imwrite('objects/pix%i.png'%i,im3)
      i+=1
cv2.imshow('norm',im)
cv2.imwrite('objects/shhh.jpg',im)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

## result:

[image]

Finally, you just need to concatenate the saved objects whit new align:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im0 = cv2.imread('objects/pix0.png',0)
im1 = cv2.imread('objects/pix1.png',0)
im2 = cv2.imread('objects/pix2.png',0)
im3 = cv2.imread('objects/pix3.png',0)
im4 = cv2.imread('objects/pix4.png',0)
im5 = cv2.imread('objects/pix5.png',0)

h0, w0 = im0.shape[:2]
h1, w1 = im1.shape[:2]
h2, w2 = im2.shape[:2]
h3, w3 = im3.shape[:2]
h4, w4 = im4.shape[:2]
h5, w5 = im5.shape[:2]
maxh=max(h0,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5)

#add 50 for space between the objects

new = np.zeros((maxh, w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+w5+50),np.uint8)
new=(255-new)
new[maxh-h0:, :w0] = im0
new[maxh-h1:, w0+10:w0+w1+10] = im1
new[maxh-h2:, w0+w1+20:w0+w1+w2+20] = im2
new[maxh-h3:, w0+w1+w2+30:w0+w1+w2+w3+30] = im3
new[maxh-h4:, w0+w1+w2+w3+40:w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+40] = im4
new[maxh-h5:, w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+50:] = im5
gray = cv2.cvtColor(new, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


cv2.imshow('norm',gray)
cv2.imwrite('objects/new_image.jpg',gray)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

## result :

[image]

for remove black lines you can comment the line `cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),1)`

so change it to `#cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),1)`

## result after comment rectangle drawing command !:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Nearly a year that i dont work with `OpenCv` ! but as working with contours was interesting for me still i can use it as well as!

Comment: I am running the code first  one but it i not saving the object on objects folder.. please help me . Thank you   @Kasra

Comment: do you create object folder ? you must create it before !

Comment: yes I did i found shhh.jpg on that folder but cv2.imwrite('objects/pix%i.png'%i,im3) i not working. i found no other object on that folder. @Kasra

Comment: do you see the rectangles around the objects ? in shhh.jpg ?

Comment: if you havent rectangles around the objects its mean that the `if` statement doesn't be execute ! so i thinks its because of the size of your image ! you need to change 60 in `if h>60` to a proper number while you see an output like that i put in answer !

Comment: I have changed h to h>15 and that gives perfect result but what will i change on the next code ? as second one is not working. @Kasra

Comment: I got the result but there is also black line in every letter how will i remove that ? thanks in advance @Kasra

Comment: you must comment rectangle drawing line ! i add it to answer ! good lock ! if you find this answer helpful you can also give up vote !

Comment: hello thanks. I am testing with other image but it i giving wrong image. sequence of object is not following why can you tell me that? I can provide you other image to try. sure I ill vote for this. @Kasra

Comment: yes its because of your contours that is not sorted ! so you need to change the name of saved objects in folder . i think there is not a regular way for resolve this problem ! anyway i attempt to find a way and add it to answer !

Comment: hello @Kasra do you have any solution. ?

Comment: hello @MarkAdward disappointing no ! i thinks its complicated to recognize the queue of the contours !

Comment: so any way my alternative solution is that we check the coordinate of h or w of any contours inside the image and , by this point that any coordinate that is near to `0` is `5` and then `a` then ... and base of that we can fide the turn of objectd

Comment: can you give me reference or code to do that ? I am new to python.  @Kasra

Comment: i see your new question ! i attempt to do it with code and give that to you as an answer !